# cursor blinking removal in terminal, how to?

Tags: c++, shell, terminal, text-cursor

I use the following lines to output my simulation's progress info in my c++ program,

```
double N=0;
double percent=0;
double total = 1000000;
for (int i; i<total; ++i)
{
    percent = 100*i/total;
    printf("\r[%6.4f%%]",percent);
}
```

It works fine!

But the problem is I see the terminal cursor keeps blinking cyclically through the numbers, this is very annoying, anyone knows how to get rid of this?

I've seen some programs like wget or ubuntu apt, they use progress bar or percentages too, but they seems no blinking cursor issue, I am wondering how did they do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just a guess: try to use a proper number of '\b' (backspace) characters instead of '\r'.

== EDIT ==

I'm not a Linux shell wizard, but this may work:

```
system("setterm -cursor off");
// ...display percentages...
system("setterm -cursor on");
```

Don't forget to `#include <cstdlib>` or `<iostream>`.

Comment: Why do you need percents? You could just write '#' characters, one after another. For example one '#' for each new 10%s.

Comment: OOPS, I love numbers :) Okay, I will try # and let you know the results, but anyway, just a google, someone said wget did not use ncurses

Comment: OOPS, it seems once it was turned off, it couldn't be turned on again

Comment: Using system is bad. The executed program after fork will do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10995085/78712 . Is this OK by you? `system("echo hello world!");`

Answer (score 23):

You can hide and show the cursor using the `DECTCEM` (DEC text cursor enable mode) mode in `DECSM` and `DECRM`:

```
fputs("\e[?25l", stdout); /* hide the cursor */

fputs("\e[?25h", stdout); /* show the cursor */
```

Comment: You mean in the loop, after this command `printf("\r[%6.4f%%]",percent);`?

Comment: Wherever they're required. Typically you'd hide the cursor before any updates, perform all the updates, then show it again at the end. You could even combine them all in one `printf` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid a blinking cursor is (as suggested) to hide the cursor temporarily.

However, that is only part of the solution.  Your program should also take this into account:

- after hiding the cursor and modifying the screen, **before** showing the cursor again **move** it back to the original location.
- hiding/showing the cursor only keeps the cursor from noticeably blinking when your updates take only a small amount of time.  If you happened to mix this with some time-consuming process, your cursor **will** blink.

The suggested solution using `setterm` is not portable; it is specific to the Linux console.  And running an executable using `system` is not really necessary.  But even running

```
system("tput civis");
...
system("tput cnorm");
```

is an improvement over using `setterm`.

Checking the source-code for `wget` doesn't find any cursor-hiding escape sequences.  What you're seeing with its progress bar is that it leaves the cursor in roughly the same place whenever it does something time-consuming.  The output to the terminal takes so little time that you do not notice the momentary rewrite of the line (by printing a carriage return, then writing most of the line over again).  If it were slower, then hiding the cursor would help — up to a point.

By the way — this cursor-hiding technique is used in the terminal drivers for some editors (vim and [vile](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/vile-snapshots/blob/master/tcap.c#L944)).

Comment: I think the actual reason why `wget` does not have this problem is because they print to `stderr` which is unbuffered, instead of `stdout` which is buffered.

Answer (score 0):

Those apps are probably using [ncurses](http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/curhello.php).  See [mvaddstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mvaddstr)

Comment: wget and fbi are two examples of programs that don't use ncurses, but are able to completely hide the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the cursor jumps around is because `stdout` is buffered, so you don't know actually how many characters are being printed at some point in time. The reason `wget` does not have a jumping cursor is that they are actually printing to `stderr` instead, which is unbuffered. Try the following:

```
fprintf(stderr, "\r[%6.4f%%]", percent);
```

This also has the advantage of not cluttering the file if you are saving the rest of the output somewhere using a pipe like:

```
$ ./executable > log.data
```

Answer (score -2):

Press insert key...if that doesn't work then press the **fn** key in your keyboard.
This will definitely work
Hope this helps