# Remove blinking underscore on console / cmd prompt

Tags: c++, windows, console, text-cursor

This probably something very simple, but Google doesn't seem to have the answer.

Is there a simple command for a console program to stop the blinking cursor?

Before my program runs it has a percentage of loading, but when it updates the cursor gets messed up and it is really annoying. I know its possible, lots of programs have it.

What command turns the blinking underscore on and off?

Comment: When I google I get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987468/cursor-blinking-removal-in-terminal-how-to) is it not what youre looking for?

Comment: I can imagine you're talking about Linux, but you don't have an OS tagged. I'm pretty sure (but could be wrong) that this depends on the OS you are using. It also may help if you to say if you want to do this on a shell or with a GUI.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Preferably any OS, but I'm using Windows.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone are you using command line or powershell?

Comment: @Borgleader Tried it, doesn't work

Comment: @TaylorFlores Command line

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can hide the cursor by calling [`SetConsoleCursorInfo`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686019(v=vs.85).aspx) .

```
#include <windows.h>

void ShowConsoleCursor(bool showFlag)
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO     cursorInfo;

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = showFlag; // set the cursor visibility
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
}

int main()
{
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to set `cursorInfo.dwSize` to value between 1 and 100, else `SetConsoleCursorInfo` will fail.