# How do I hide the mouse cursor in a Win32 console?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a function that sets a Win32 console to full screen. The problem is when it goes into full screen, it's not hiding the mouse cursor.

It doesn't seem to matter if it's in full screen or not. The mouse cursor still shows when I call ShowCursor(FALSE). How can it be hidden?

As in the docs for ShowCursor(), the cursor will hide if the function returns a value greater than 0.  If it's negative, it will hide. The value is returning -2 for me, so it should hide in this case, but it is not.

```
bool Console::setFullScreen(const bool fullScreen)
{
HWND handle;

if (fullScreen)
{
    // Hide the scrollbar
    showScrollBar(false);

    // Set the window style
    handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE);
    style &= ~(WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME);
    SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, style);

    // Set the window to full screen in windowed mode
    ShowWindow(getHandle(), SW_MAXIMIZE);   

    // Hide the cursor
    ShowCursor(FALSE);   // Fails
}
else
{
    showScrollBar(true);

    // Set the window style
    handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE);
    style |= WS_BORDER;
    style |= WS_CAPTION;
    style |= WS_THICKFRAME;

    SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, style);

    // Set the window to full screen in windowed mode
    ShowWindow(getHandle(), SW_NORMAL); 

    // Show the cursor
    ShowCursor(TRUE);
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Console windows are hosted in another process. Hiding the mouse cursor for your process won't hide it for the console process.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I suppose moving the mouse's cursor position off the screen programmatically is an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028808/blinking-underscore-with-console ?

Comment: Maximized is not the same as fullscreen, hardware fullscreen console is not supported on Windows Vista+.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried this, but you can probably change the mouse cursor of the console window by calling `GetConsoleWindow` to get the `HWND` of the console window, then calling `SetClassLong` to set the cursor.

```
HCURSOR hNewCursor = LoadCursor(/* whatever*/);
SetClassLong(GetConsoleWindow(), GCL_HCURSOR, hNewCursor);
```

To make the cursor disappear, create a cursor which is entirely transparent.

Comment: I tried this, and I'm still getting the default cursor.

Comment: Console windows are hosted in another process. You can't call `SetClassLong` for a window class belonging to another process and you can't pass a cursor handle from *your* process.