# Let user type in the middle of string (c/c++)?

Tags: c++, c, console

Normally c/cpp string displayed in console only allows user to type after it.

Is there any simple way to let user to type in the middle of the output string, e.g fill in the blank:

Mr ____ is the teacher.

std::cout can print it easily, but how to let user type directly in the blank with simple code and read it? And e.g. if the name is long the move the printed character to the right?

Comment: There is no such language as "C/C++". Please choose one, the answers will vary depending on that.

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have a way to do this.

Comment: your really looking at 3 separate strings.  the first string is fixed.  The second string is input from the user  The third string is fixed in content but not in location.  You can use curses, or the ANSI escape sequences to handle the actual display

Comment: One difference between C and C++ is that C++ has the `std::string` type which manages memory for you and you can query it for length.  The C language only has arrays of characters, and if the array is not terminated by a nul character, you run into Undefined Behavior.  So, edit your tags with the single language you are using.

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for controlling a console/terminal. Neither of the languages you ask about has any notion of that -- they both only know *streams* of input and output. This is a simple abstraction, input and output are done character by character, in sequence. Input doesn't have to come from a keyboard, output doesn't have to be a screen or terminal ...

Controlling the contents of a screen is very platform-dependent. If you are on windows, the windows API provides [a bunch of functions for controlling a console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions).

If you want to do something cross-platform, have a look at `curses`. There are implementations for many platforms, like `ncurses` (often used on *nix systems) and `pdcurses` (which is quite good for windows) and they all provide the same interface.

To learn about `curses` programming, the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is a good start. Just replace `#include <ncurses.h>` with `#include <curses.h>` so your code isn't tied specifically to `ncurses` but works with any `curses` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely do this (I mean, ever played snake? All games were on terminals back then, and your problem is much simpler than writing a game).

A trick is using `\r`, which is a carriage return. That character will slide you back to the start of the line, allowing you to overwrite the previous string. This is commonly used for loading animations like

[---]

[=---]

[==-]

[===]

To prevent forcing the user to hit enter before sending data, I'll show a Linux/Mac solution.

```
system("/bin/stty raw"); // Get keystrokes immediately, #include <stdlib.h>
string s;
char c;
cout << "Mr _ is the teacher." << flush;
while( c = getchar() ) { // #include <stdio.h>
    if( c == 3 ) // CTRL+C
        exit(1);
    if( c == 13 ) { // Newline
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }
    if( c == 127 ) { // Backspace
        if( s.size() > 0 )
            s.pop_back();
    } else {
        s += c;
    }
    cout << "\r"; // Reset the cursor
    cout << "Mr " << s << "_ is the teacher.  " << flush; // Spaces to cover invalid backspace character
    cout << "\r"; // Reset the cursor
    cout << "Mr " << s << "_ is the teacher." << flush;
}
system("/bin/stty cooked"); // Go back to buffered input
```

This can be done in Windows by importing `#include<conio.h>`, and then using `getch()` instead of `getchar()`. (You don't need any stty system commands)

Make sure to use your platform-specific `#ifdef`'s to make your code portable!

Comment: There are ways to hide the cursor if you're a bit OCD about it like I am. In fact, I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028808/blinking-underscore-with-console) that question in the past. You can research a Linux alternative as well.

Comment: The problem is that not all consoles or terminals process a CR (Carriage Return) in the same manner.  Some may return the carriage to the beginning of the text line, others may return to the beginning of the line *and advance to the next line*.  This should be tested.  Also, the console or terminal emulator should be standardized to something like ANSI or VT100.

Comment: Very old versions of Mac use `\r` as a newline. I haven't heard of any system other than those that won't pull the cursor back to the beginning though (The main debate is `\r\n` vs `\n` as newline, not `\r` being a carriage return), so I wouldn't really worry about it. `/bin/stty raw` is more of a dependency IMO.