# change carret's shape on windows terminal

Tags: windows, caret, text-cursor

I want to set the text cursor (caret) of my console app from BLOCK (the default) to _ or |.

I [Remove blinking underscore on console / cmd prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028808/remove-blinking-underscore-on-console-cmd-prompt) - but it does not mention how to modify the cursor. Documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN is not directly trivial to me.

Comment: That same sample works. You just have to update the `dwSize` to change the size.

Comment: Can i change it to  a beam, or is it bound to be like in good old text mode 0x03?

Comment: The documentation explains what you can do to the caret size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by Raymond Chen (for those who don't know who he is: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)

This is what I used for block cursor:

```
        HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo;

        GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
        cursorInfo.bVisible = true;
        cursorInfo.dwSize = 100;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
```

And for underscore cursor:

```
        HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo;

        GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
        cursorInfo.bVisible = true;
        cursorInfo.dwSize = 10;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Microsoft's preferred modern solution which uses [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-visibility).

Before we do anything, we must set the console mode to **ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING** like:

```
DWORD dwMode{};
GetConsoleMode(mHandleConsoleOutput, &dwMode);
dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
SetConsoleMode(mHandleConsoleOutput, dwMode);
```

After that we can use those sequences and, for example, to make the shape of the caret a blinking block use:

```
cout << "\x1b[1\x20q";
```